# Rails: Bundle path source?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, bundler

OK, I'm trying to figure out how to get a gem install that the install script fails due to a space in the path name.  I've tried everything I could, but for some reason the bundle install still picks up the long path rather than the symlinked path I have without the spaces.

Where does it pick up these paths?

I've tried updating bundle config but it still list the long path as the path to the local app rather than the new symlink path.  If I update, it only does it for the local user not the local app.

I am stuck and I've crashed my machine by trying to remove the space in the volume name, I've added all the environment variables I can think of, I'm at a loss to get the bundler to install without referencing the path with a space in it.

I've tried contacting the developers for the gem, no love.  I just need to get the whole app to use the symlink path rather than the /Volumes/Macintosh HD/ path.  Ideas?  suggestions?  crazy ideas?  I'm willing to give anything a shot at this point.

Update 12/16:
Gem is FFI.
Here's the Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
require 'rubygems'

gem 'rails', '3.0.8'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'haml'
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth-openid'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-github'
gem "settingslogic"
gem 'composite_primary_keys'


# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'pg'
gem 'squeel'
gem 'sqlite-ruby'
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.2.6'
gem "bcrypt-ruby", :require => "bcrypt"

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
  gem 'hpricot', :require => false #html2haml
  gem 'ruby_parser', :require => false # html2haml
  gem 'pickle'
  gem 'awesome_print', :require => 'ap'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end

group :development do
  gem 'heroku', :require => false
  gem 'sass'
end

group :test do
  gem 'shoulda'
  gem 'cucumber-rails'
  gem 'spork', '~> 0.9.0.rc3'
  gem 'guard-spork'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end
```

Comment: I don't see FFI in your Gemfile.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it was a dependency...

Answer (score 0):

1. Install [rvm](http://beginrescueend.com/)
2. Create a [gemset](http://beginrescueend.com/gemsets/)
3. Add a [`.rvmrc`](http://beginrescueend.com/workflow/rvmrc/) file to your `RAILS_ROOT` directory.
4. `cd` into your `RAILS_ROOT` directory.
5. Run `bundle install`.

Comment: rvm was already installed. I added the gemset via "rvm gemset create webapp".  Added a .rvmrc fill to the RAILS_ROOT.  Bundle Install still fails, still using the /Volumes/ path

Comment: Please post the output from `rvm current` and `gem environment`.

Comment: Ross$ rvm current
ruby-1.9.2-p180
Ross$ gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.6.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 180) [x86_64-darwin11.0.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/Ross/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/Ross/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/Ross/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-11
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/Ross/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180
     - ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global

Comment: - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/

Comment: It looks like you skipped the "use a gemset" step. I would strongly suggest trying that, as it will rule out your global gem environment being the culprit. Plus, gemsets, are just a nice way to wall off your gems for a given app. Note that if you did indeed create a gemset, you still have to specify that you want to use it in the .rvmrc file.

Comment: OK, I fixed that... GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/Ross/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@webapp
     - /Users/Ross/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global  Bundle install still fails

Comment: Weird. What gem is this? Also, you might want to add your Gemfile to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I just removed the space in the volume name, I tried fixing the install script but I'd fix one area and it would error out in another.